How to Automatically Reassign Pending Approvals in Power Automate When Approvers Are Out of Office
I'm working on automating the reassignment of pending approvals in Power Automate when the assigned approvers are Out of Office (OOF). We have multiple workflows that use the "Start and wait for an approval" action, assigning approval tasks to various managers.
Objectives:
Centralized Solution: Implement a flow that can automatically reassign pending approvals without modifying each existing workflow.
Retrieve Pending Approvals: Get a list of all pending approval requests along with their assigned approvers.
Check OOF Status: Determine if an approver has enabled their Out of Office status in Outlook.
Reassign Approvals: If the approver is OOF, reassign the approval to a designated backup approver specified in a SharePoint list.
Notify Backup Approver: Optionally send a notification to the backup approver about the reassigned approval.
What I've Tried So Far:
Retrieving Pending Approvals:
Used the Microsoft Dataverse connector to access the "Approvals" table.
Attempted to use the "List rows" action with a filter query statuscode eq 1 to get pending approvals.
Encountered difficulty in retrieving the assigned approver's details (email or user ID).
Checking OOF Status:
Used the "Get mailbox automatic replies" action from the Office 365 Outlook connector to check if a user is OOF.
Able to determine OOF status when I have the approver's email.
Reassigning Approvals:
Tried to update the approval record in Dataverse to change the assigned approver.
Not sure if updating the "msdyn_flow_approvalassignedto" field is the correct approach.
Concerned about potential issues or limitations with modifying approval records directly.
Challenges:
Accessing Assigned Approvers:
The "Approvals" table doesn't provide clear information on the assigned approvers.
Need a reliable way to get the approver's email or user ID to check their OOF status.
Updating Approval Assignments:
Uncertain about the correct method to reassign approvals programmatically.
Worried about breaking the approval workflow or causing inconsistencies.
Questions:
How can I retrieve all pending approvals along with their assigned approvers' details (e.g., email addresses) using Power Automate connectors?
What is the proper way to programmatically reassign an approval request to a different user in Power Automate?
Are there any limitations or best practices when accessing and modifying approvals stored in Dataverse?
Is there an alternative approach to achieve this automatic reassignment without directly modifying the existing workflows or the Dataverse records?
Additional Information:
Environment: Using Power Automate (cloud flows) and Office 365.
Data Source for Backup Approvers: We have a SharePoint list mapping primary approvers to their backup approvers.
Constraints: Cannot modify the existing workflows due to their large number and complexity.
Not Using: Microsoft Planner is not being used in this scenario.
